# How to execute two queries based on case condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute queries based on condition within single table,here is my query in sql server.
where PATTERN is column name and is set to 0 as default value 
I want to display result into only one cell of excel sheet. I linked SQL server and Excel sheet.

```
IF ([PATTERN] = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT PATTERN,COLOR,SHIFT  FROM [DEFECT_RESULTS]
END
ELSE
   SELECT MODEL,COLOR  FROM [DEFECT_RESULTS]
```

pattern column is present then still following error is displaying
error: Invalid column name 'PATTERN'.

Comment: In the IF, it does not know about the field called PATTERN, which is why you are getting an error. It is like you doing `select something;` who knows what that something is.

Comment: Post whole query as it lacks some details. People will be able to answer more accurately then :)

Comment: IF exists (SELECT 1 FROM [PAINT_SHOP].[dbo].[DEFECT_RESULTS] where PATTERN=1)
BEGIN
    SELECT PATTERN,COLOR,SHIFT  FROM [PAINT_SHOP].[dbo]. [DEFECT_RESULTS]
END
ELSE
begin
   SELECT MODEL,COLOR,shift FROM [PAINT_SHOP].[dbo].[DEFECT_RESULTS]
   end  ---i tried with this also ...its giving same results for both condition PATTERN=1 and PATTERN=0

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: These are some sample data,... i want to filter through PATTERN value 
SHIFT COLOR MODEL PATTERN
B         30              20         0
B           31           20    0
A         30            21         1
A        31            21         1

Comment: As a "trainee", you should be asking your "trainers" for guidance and answers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform a query in the `if` condition. SQL doesn't know what table/function you're referring to as it stands.

Something like

```
if exists (select 1 from DEFECT_RESULTS where PATTERN = 1)
begin
  …
```

Which will do the true side of the `if` if any row in `DEFECT_RESULTS` matches. You may need a more specific condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @pattern int
if (@pattern=1)
begin
SELECT PATTERN,COLOR,SHIFT  FROM [DEFECT_RESULTS]
end
else if(@pattern=0) 
begin
SELECT MODEL,COLOR  FROM [DEFECT_RESULTS]
end
```

Comment: No... its giving same results for both condition PATTERN=1 and also for PATTERN=0

Comment: @shashidhardeshpande if you pass 1 means first select query should execute and if you pass 0 means second select query should run this is your requirement

Comment: The DEFECT_RESULTS table contain column called PATTERN,for some rows values are default 0 and others are set to 1. But on executing your given query it is giving all 0's and 1's including row values. I am also unable to find reason

Comment: what is your requirement

Comment: Requirement: i have two queries that executes based on PATTERN value. pattern column is int type and 0 is set as default value. In some cases 1 is pushed into PATTERN column. So i want to filter by PATTERN column value.

Comment: please pass a variable pattern as int  if it is pattern=1 then 1st query pattern-0 then 2nd query

Comment: Please consider to include description for the applied solution for the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

A single query cannot return 2 columns sometimes and 3 columns at other times.  Perhaps you just want two queries:

```
SELECT PATTERN, COLOR, SHIFT
FROM [DEFECT_RESULTS]
WHERE PATTERN = 1;

SELECT MODEL, COLOR
FROM [DEFECT_RESULTS]
WHERE PATTERN = 0;
```

Comment: correct but i need to display the result in only one cell of excel sheet. I am linking SQL query to excel sheet,...